# Solution of Poisson's equation with a linear term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Consider the partial differential equation

$$ \Delta u = au - b,~~~~~ x \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n},~a,b>0$$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0~~ \text{on}~ \partial \Omega.$$
Using some transformation, is there any way to convert it into the form
$$ \Delta v = c,~~~~~ x \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$$
with some appropriate boundary conditions. Because I know, how to handle Poisson's equation but don't know how to handle this equation, that is, how to derive solution to this PDE?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I don't think it's possible. That's because the behavior of the equation depends strongly on $a$ (and its comparison to the first eigenvalue of the laplacian). What is your underlying problem? Maybe it can be addressed directly?

Comment: Is it possible to derive classical solution to first PDE?

Comment: I wonder do you a specific goal in mind @ManojKumar? Even if you can transform it to $\Delta v= c$ in $\Omega$ you won’t be able to find an explicit solution unless you have a specific $\Omega$ in mind (for example a ball)

Comment: Yes, domain can be taken unit ball and then we can try to expand it. But is there any technique to obtain explicit solution to this problem even on unit ball?

Comment: On the unit ball you could look for a radial solution $u(r)$ and turn your problem to an ODE.